# Reading XML file with jQuery after XML was modified

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have a good jquery code to read my XML file. The only problem is that if i change the XML file, my html somehow displays the old values from XML. I tried this with JAvascript first and now the same thing happens with Jquery.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<body>
<div id="recentNews">
    <h2>Recent News</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get('News/news.xml', function (d) {
                $('body').find('#recentNews').append('<h1> Here are the news: </h1><dl />');
                $(d).find('news').each(function () {
                    var $news = $(this);
                    var nText = $news.find('newsText').text();
                    var nImage = $news.find('newsImage').text();

                    var html = '<dt> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="News/' + nImage + '" /> </dt>';
                    html += '<dd> <span class="loadingPic" alt="Loading" />';
                    html += '<p> ' + nText + '</p>';
                    html += '</dd>';

                    $('dl').append($(html));

                    $('.loadingPic').fadeOut(1400);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my news.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<recentNews>
  <news>
    <newsText>
      <![CDATA[Grand OPening!]]>
    </newsText>
    <newsImage>
      <![CDATA[opening.jpg]]>
    </newsImage>
  </news>

  <news>
    <newsText>
      <![CDATA[Merry Christmas!]]>
    </newsText>
    <newsImage>
      <![CDATA[christmas.png]]>
    </newsImage>
  </news>

</recentNews>
```

if i change the newsText from Merry Christmas to Happy Holidays, it will still somehow remember and display Merry Christmas...

any idea why is this happening ? the same happens with Javascipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 has a weird way of clearing the cache memory. but that seemed to be the problem